# how to calculate travel time using source and destination times?

Tags: php, mysql, time, strtotime

Departure_Time at source is `18:25` and Arrival_Time at destination is `05:20` so

```
 tt2.Arrival_Time -tt1.Departure_Time As Travel_Time
```

gives `-130500` instead `10:55H`  how to achive this? any help will be appretiated..many thanks.!!

**edit**- destination time is of second day..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php adding and subtracting time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22618585/php-adding-and-subtracting-time)

Comment: What exactly is in `Arrival_Time` and `Departure_Time`?

Comment: @IncredibleHat   where is wrong sir?...plz guide me

Comment: datatype of both column is TIME  having values 18:25:00  and 05:20:00  it is complete schedule of time  at each station.. i want to calculate travel time giving source and destination as value..

Comment: So... just a time, no date. How would it know if it spans one day, or two, or no days? Plus, what happens if the source and destination are in different timezones? I will not be able to help with this. Way too little data to go on, too much lacking logic. Sorry... hope someone else can help.

Comment: @IncredibleHat  thanks u sir..i think i need to add day column as day spans..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a code for you that you can modify the difference of days between departure and arrival.But but but this code is only and only for a single time zone.If you have different times in different time zones that's different!

```
<?php
/**/
$Departure_Time='05:20';//Set Departure time
$Arrival_Time='18:30';//Set Arrival time
$dayDifference=0;//You can modify this 
/**/
$a=strtotime($Departure_Time);
$b=strtotime($Arrival_Time.' + '.($dayDifference*24).' Hours');
$interval = ($b - $a) / 60;
$traveltime=date("i:s",$interval);
echo $traveltime;
?>
```

And I really don't have any ideas why did I use i:s for hour and minute!

But anyway it works!

Tell me if you have any problem with the code :)

Comment: yes it works ..:) thanks...and yes time zone doesn't change in this case, only one standard time and within the country..

Comment: Is that a class project?

Comment: I don't understand what are you saying.You can explain it in your question post so I can try my best to give a solution to you