# How to store time as day span..as integer?

Tags: php, mysql

I had a table structure as follows.. column `SrNo` `Arrival_Time` and Day. I want desired output as `Day` column in following pattern... How to store that? Using mysql query or php code snippet...? Day value should be in integer format. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

```
CREATE TABLE `travel_time` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `SrNo` int(3) default NULL,
  `Arrival_Time` time default NULL,
  `Day` int(1) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=61 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `travel_time`
--

INSERT INTO `travel_time` (`id`, `SrNo`, `Arrival_Time`, `Day`) VALUES
(1, 1, '18:25:00', 1),
(2, 2, '19:50:00', 1),
(3, 3, '21:22:00', 1),
(4, 4, '22:23:00', 1),
(5, 5, '23:18:00', 1),
(6, 6, '00:30:00', 2),
(7, 7, '02:38:00', 2),
(8, 8, '03:20:00', 2),
(9, 9, '04:13:00', 2),
(10, 10, '04:53:00', 2),
(11, 11, '05:20:00', 2),
(12, 12, '06:55:00', 2),
(13, 13, '08:37:00', 2),
(14, 14, '10:10:00', 2),
(15, 15, '11:05:00', 2),
(16, 16, '11:22:00', 2),
(17, 17, '12:06:00', 2),
(18, 18, '13:22:00', 2),
(19, 19, '14:03:00', 2),
(20, 20, '14:40:00', 2),
(21, 21, '16:30:00', 2),
(22, 22, '17:28:00', 2),
(23, 23, '18:20:00', 2),
(24, 24, '19:15:00', 2),
(25, 25, '20:00:00', 2),
(26, 26, '21:18:00', 2),
(27, 27, '22:53:00', 2),
(28, 28, '23:51:00', 2),
(29, 29, '01:52:00', 3),
(30, 30, '04:10:00', 3),
(31, 1, '21:50:00', 1),
(32, 2, '23:30:00', 1),
(33, 3, '01:25:00', 2),
(34, 4, '02:27:00', 2),
(35, 5, '03:55:00', 2),
(36, 6, '05:45:00', 2),
(37, 7, '05:55:00', 2),
(38, 8, '06:43:00', 2),
(39, 9, '07:43:00', 2),
(40, 10, '09:00:00', 2),
(41, 11, '10:45:00', 2),
(42, 12, '11:40:00', 2),
(43, 13, '12:06:00', 2),
(44, 14, '13:37:00', 2),
(45, 15, '14:13:00', 2),
(46, 16, '14:29:00', 2),
(47, 17, '15:40:00', 2),
(48, 18, '16:43:00', 2),
(49, 19, '18:22:00', 2),
(50, 20, '19:22:00', 2),
(51, 21, '19:49:00', 2),
(52, 22, '20:24:00', 2),
(53, 23, '21:20:00', 2),
(54, 24, '21:53:00', 2),
(55, 25, '23:50:00', 2),
(56, 26, '01:13:00', 3),
(57, 27, '02:08:00', 3),
(58, 28, '03:27:00', 3),
(59, 29, '05:05:00', 3),
(60, 30, '06:50:00', 3);
```

Comment: @ Mobin F.R.G  .. how to achive this...sir

Comment: What are you asking? Do you want the php code that returns monday as 1 for example?

Comment: no day as 1 until its time 24:00:00 after that day as 2 ..how to store that..

Comment: Ok I'm trying to write query for that

Comment: Are these data correctly stored? I see  there is 02:38:00 which is day 2!.Do you want to put day 2 if it is more than 24hrs? Do you want to update current data or insert more?

Comment: yes it is correctly stored.. as day 2 started from id no 6...i want to insert more...its just sample..

Comment: When should it be day 2? What is the condition? I don't understand this

Comment: day 2 started after 24:00:00 or 23:59:00(i dont know exactly when day changes) until the next 24:00:00 hours then day 3.. this cycle continues until SrNo comes to 30 then next SrNo from 1..to ..so on

Comment: Ok now I understood!

Comment: But Day is part of the dataset !?! Even after reading your answer, I still have no idea what you're asking

Comment: @Strawberry He wants to compute day based on the other columns.  I think day is shown just to demonstrate what is wanted here.

Comment: @Strawberry.  Yes exactly..Day based on other column.. give me query to insert day..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get the query working, after about 45 minutes of work.  Here it is:

```
SELECT id, SrNo, Arrival_Time,
    @day := if(m2 = 1, 1, if(m1 = 1, @day + 1, @day)) AS Day
FROM
(
    SELECT
        t1.id,
        t1.SrNo,
        t1.Arrival_Time,
        CASE WHEN t1.Arrival_time < t2.Arrival_time THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS m1,
        CASE WHEN t1.SrNo < t2.SrNo THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS m2
    FROM travel_time t1
    LEFT JOIN travel_time t2
        ON t1.id = t2.id + 1
) t1, (SELECT @day:=1) AS t
ORDER BY id;
```

### Demo

The inner query, aliased as `t1`, selects all data columns, along with two markers, `m1` and `m2`.  The `m1` marker keeps track of whether we have rolled over to a new day, in which case the day needs to be incremented by one.  The `m2` marker keeps track of whether we have reset the `SrNo` sequence, in which case the day also needs to be reset to 1.

Big lesson learned: We have to first materialize the self join *before* attempting to iterate with a user variable.  Without the `t1` subquery trick, my solution kept failing.  Check the demo below to see this in action.

**Edit:**

If you need an actual table which contains this data, then I recommend using `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` with my query:

```
INSERT INTO travel_time_new (id, SrNo, Arrival_Time, Day)
SELECT ...    -- my query from above
```

This requires creating a new table called `travel_time_new` which also contains a new column for the day.  You may then delete the original `travel_time` table, and then rename the new table to the old one.

I suggest this because updating your current table using my answer would require joining to my query, and that might have caveats as it is using user variables.

Comment: @user7808845 I just made an update to fix it, try the demo link again.  You asked a really hard question.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen I didn't get the point of SrNo.Can you explain it to me, please? I don't know how is SrNo working in your query :)

Comment: @MobinF.R.G I also didn't get that comment.  By inspection, if you look at the expected output, you'll notice _two_ sequences.  One is by day, which rolls over every time we pass midnight, as ordered by the `id`.  But the other is by `SrNo`, which resets the day to one each time that the `SrNo` sequence is also reset.  I based my answer on what I saw, not really what I read.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen I thought like that first.But if you look at id 30-35 everything is different.Day is changing but the SrNo is as same as the previous one

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  sir.. can you give me the insert query..to insert value in Day Column ...if i make day column empty..actually i dont want select table..i just want to insert value into day Column..

Comment: You could update your table by joining to my query.  Or, you could use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` with my query into a new table, then drop the old table.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  Thank you.. :)

Answer (score 0):

According to this question :[how to calculate travel time using source and destination times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51386237/how-to-calculate-travel-time-using-source-and-destination-times/51388906?noredirect=1#comment89759987_51388906)
 I think you need a PHP script for this.

I wrote a code that you can set the time and run script.Then the Time you have set will be inserted to table.
This code doesn't recognize if the hour is passed 23:59 because it will ruin the table since there is nothing more than 23:51 in your table and it's working! This code just checks if the input time is after or before the last entered time in table then changes the day.

I hope this is the code you are looking for:

```
<?php
$insertTime="07:10";
//Connect to Database
$conn=new mysqli($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
if (!$conn) {
die("Error Connecting To Database: ".mysqli_connect_error()."<br/>");
}
$readlastdate="SELECT * FROM travel_time  ORDER BY `travel_time`.`id` DESC";
$readresult=mysqli_query($conn,$readlastdate);
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($readresult)) {
$time=date("H:i:s",strtotime($row['Arrival_Time']));
$readDay=$row['Day'];
$TimeToInsert=date("H:i:s",strtotime($insertTime));

if ($TimeToInsert < $time) {
    $insertday=$readDay+1;
        $sql="
        INSERT INTO travel_time (`SrNo`,`Arrival_Time`,`Day`)
        VALUES ('".($row['SrNo']+1)."','".$TimeToInsert."','".$insertday."' )
        ";
        if (mysqli_query($conn,$sql)) {
            break;
        }else{echo mysqli_error($conn)."<br/>";}
}else{
    $elsesql="INSERT INTO travel_time (`SrNo`,`Arrival_Time`,`Day`)
    VALUES ('".($row['SrNo']+1)."','".$TimeToInsert."','".$readDay."' )
    ";
}
}
?>
```

I hope this helps you

P.S:edit the database information