# How to calculate duration between to time using php?

Tags: php, time

I want to calculate time duration between 23:10 and 01:30. I need to get 02:20, but I got about 22 hours.
Now I use Carbon library e.g.

```
Carbon::parse($request->departure_time)->diffInMinutes(Carbon::parse($request->arrival_time), false);
```

Comment: It appears from your question that you are comparing times instead of datetimes.

Comment: Your issue is that `Carbon` generates `DateTime`, so while you only feed time, the date is also attatched to it and then they are compared. You can try reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22618649/4516316) which gives a good method. But if you have the dates as well, then you can use them along with the time to get accurate results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add dates because php thinks it's same day

for example

```
$startTime = "2011-01-03 23:10";
$endTime = "2011-01-04 01:30";
```